# How can I make USB recognized in Windows 10 that works on virtualbox?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, virtualbox, linux-mint

I'm currently using Linux Mint 18.
I installed virtualbox on my linux, and I'm running Windows 10 on virtualbox. (it works properly)

When I install USB device on my desktop, I want it to be recognized in Windows 10 that runs on virtualbox.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the OS in the virtual box. Open the console. in the top menu you will see devices, go to usb -> and click the usb you have connected.